# Batch rename directories?

Tags: rename, batch, batch-rename

I have several directories with the format of the year, month, and day followed by a description of the event. For example: "2012 05 26 - EventA", "2012 05 26 - EventB". What I would like to do is rename all these directories so that the spaces between the numbers in the date are replaced with dashes. Thus, "2012 05 26 - EventA" becomes "2012-05-26 - EventA". I know I can do this one folder at a time with the mv command, but is there a way to do this in a batch process with wildcards somehow?

Comment: can you wait for 10 mins, i will write in c++ or bash

Comment: is there only that directorys?

Comment: There are 50 or so directories. That's just the format they're in.

Comment: is there only 2012 year files

Comment: There are several years accounted for. However, the answer below led me to a program that does the trick. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try pyRenamer: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/pyrenamer-easy-mass-file-renaming-in.html

or similar: http://alternativeto.net/software/pyrenamer/?platform=linux&license=free

Comment: That second link led me to GPRename, which seems to do the trick after some messing around. Thanks!

Comment: pyRenamer is the one I use, and is pretty powerful, but perhaps not as straightforward as it could be.  Personally, I think it's worth learning, especially for music files, where you might want to normalize the file naming.  It supports renaming using metadata for music and pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `mmv`.

`sudo aptitude install mmv`

`#> mmv "201? * * - Event?" "201#1-#2-#3 - Event#4"`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to rename multiple directories (folders, not files) and could not figure out if this is possible with pyRenamer. GPRename (http://gprename.sourceforge.net/) does the trick quite nicely though.

Ubuntu users should have GPRename in their reposiories and can run this command to install GPRename:

`sudo apt-get install gprename`

Answer (score 0):

Use [rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/prename.1.html) (with the `-n` option to test the changes):

```
rename 'm/(\d{4}) (\d{2}) (.*)/;$_="$1-$2-$3"' *
```

Rename is provided by perl so you may need to install it (don't know if it's part of the stock Ubuntu install):

```
sudo apt-get install perl
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot rename batch files using `mv` command. You need to write shell scripts, you can get the scripts by doing a google search or you can use the tools mentioned above.